# How to get the browser set in test configuration in VSTS?

Tags: testing, browser, configuration, automation, azure-devops

I have setup and environment to build and automate the UI test cases using selenium. We can change the test configuration to run the test cases using different browser. However I wanted to know , how can we get the configuration values used during the test run? e.g. If i have three configuration say IE, Chrome, Firefox. I want to run the selected automated test cases using the configuration set. I just need the variable name that can be used to get the configuration. E.g. $(test.rundid), is there something as $(test.configuration)?

Thanks,
Abhijit

Comment: Do you have any code to show us what you've done so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure Multi-configuration execution plan to do that:

1. Add a variable with configurations value (e.g. TargetBrowser=> IE, Chrome, Firefox)
2. Choose **Multi-configuration** and specify `TargetBrowser` as multiplers
   Article: Running tests in parallel using VSTS Release Management (apply to build)

[image]

Article: [Running tests in parallel using VSTS Release Management](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jikuma/2016/12/13/run-phase-on-multiple-agents-in-parallel/) (apply to build)

Then, you can [supply run time parameters to tests](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/09/04/supplying-run-time-parameters-to-tests/).

For example:

The TestRunParameters section in RunSettings File:

```
<TestRunParameters>
  <Parameter name="browser" value="IE"/>
</TestRunParameters>
```

Get the corresponding value by using TestContext.Properties:

```
 String app url=TestContext.Properties["browser"].ToString();
//TODO specify UI Test browser.
```

Specify the parameter in Override TestRunParameters of Visual Studio Test task:

```
appUrl=$(TargetBrowser)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This will work when we always want to run the testcases in all browsers. However i want to give the control in hands of QA team. In the Test -> Configurations, we can add Test configuration variables as Browser, OS, Device etc, and create combination of these variables as Test Configuration. This configuration then can be set to the individual Test cases. Once this is done, if we run the test cases with automated test case execution, the respective test case should receive the configuration variable values as set in the Test configuration. Is this possible?

Comment: Do not find the way to do it.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Is there a way now ( November 2019) to achieve this? To get configuration at runtime when QA launched a specifc test case through testcontext (or other means)?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I also couldn't find a way to call on Test Configuration variables.

But expanding on @pabrams, I've implemented a release with multiple stages, each overwriting the Pipeline Variable 'TargetEnvironment' with desired environment to test against

[Release Structure with Stages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh5xp.png)

[Where 'TargetEnvironment' is overwritten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGQPL.png)

And I expanded to configure on browser. I created another release-pipeline that sets a 'Browser' variable.

[Where I set the variable in the new Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq01B.png)

Lastly, I had to edit my source code to read these when the pipeline runs. I Call the following method where I set the environment:

```
        public static string GetUrlBasedOnEnvironment()
    {
        switch (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TargetEnvironment").ToLower())
        {
            case "development":
                return Development.url;
            case "staging":
                return Staging.url;
            case "preview":
                return Preview.url;
            case "production":
                return Production.url;
            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("TargetEnvironment");
        }
```

And here for browser:

```
{
    public static IWebDriver getDriverBasedOnBrowser()
    {
        switch (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Browser").ToLower())
        {
            case "chrome":
                return new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), new ChromeOptions(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
            case "edge":
                var options = new EdgeOptions();
                options.UseChromium = true; //needed to test on new edge w/ chromium
                return new EdgeDriver(options);
            case "firefox":
                return new FirefoxDriver();
            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Browser");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a variable for this, you can just use different test plans or test suites. You set those to only run certain configurations, and associate each one with a different release.  In each of those releases, you just pass the override parameter, specifying the browser explicitly based on test plan/suite.
If you want to get fancy, you could use variables to pass to task groups to save on duplication.